# NVM on Windows 10: node is installed but cannot use it

Tags: node.js, windows-10, nvm

Apologies as I am a MacOS user who has used NVM for a long time, trying to configure on Windows.

Following instruction found here on SO, I downloaded and ran nvm setup.  I took all the default options, and it installed into AppData as expected.  I can run `nvm` and everything.

I ran `nvm install 12.18.1`. It downloaded and installed.

I type `nvm list` and in shows `12.18.1`

However, when I try to run something like `node --version` I get this:

[image]

If I try to run `nvm use 12.18.1` i get this odd error:

[image]

As a MacOS and Unix user at this point I am stuck. I know it has to be some sort of path issue. I have searched here on SO and elsewhere and none of the answers have this series of errors.  I have tried the command

> In the C:\Program Files\ folder use cmd to run mklink /D /J nodejs C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\nvm[node version]

But there is no `nodejs` folder in the Program Files folder.

My environment variables look OK:
[image]

Comment: Just to make sure: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)?

Comment: nvm-windows, found here https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Comment: Try running the console with admin rights, and nvm install again

Comment: I tried that.  I never did get it to work. Wound up installing node without nvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and after a few hours of trying different things and reinstalling nvm a few times, I have somehow resolved the problem. I am only partially aware of how and I will present that below:

On my last try before it worked I did 3 things:

1. I uninstalled a software called *hamachi* (https://hamachi.en.softonic.com/)
2. I ran *OneClick Optimizer* utility from *BitDefender antivirus* a couple of times until it reported all issues resolved (it did *Disk Cleanup*, Registry Cleanup and Privacy Cleanup)
3. I have rebooted the computer

**I did all these 3 things with nvm, nodejs, npm uninstalled and no folders left at the install locations.**

Then I ran the nvm installer again and it worked like a charm, both *nvm install* and *nvm use*

I think number 2 in the list above did it, because I remember messing with nvm a while ago and probably I have had something broken.

This is my very first answer on stackoverflow, I hope it helps someone.